# AFNetworking/NSURLSession takes long to create more than 100 tasks to download files

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlsession

My apps need to download many files and I use a for loop to create download tasks. Following method is the one provided by AFNetworking.

```
- (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                         progress:(void (^)(NSProgress *downloadProgress)) downloadProgressBlock
                                      destination:(NSURL * (^)(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response))destination
                                completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error))completionHandler{
__block NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = nil;
url_session_manager_create_task_safely(^{
    downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
});

[self addDelegateForDownloadTask:downloadTask progress:downloadProgressBlock destination:destination completionHandler:completionHandler];

return downloadTask;
```

}

My codes would be like:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i<= 500; i++) {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = array[i];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:downloadProgress destination:^NSURL * _Nonnull(NSURL * _Nonnull targetPath, NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response) {
        return destinationPath;
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, NSURL * _Nullable filePath, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        completionBlock(filePath,error);
    }];

    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

The problem is

```
downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
```

this line takes relatively long to done, which means if excute it for 500 times, it gonna take 5~6 seconds.

My app pop up an alertView to ask users whether to download, and if they tap Yes, it will do something like the for loop and as a result the UI will stuck there for 5~6 seconds until all the tasks are created.

I am not sure if I did correct or if there are some other way to make batch downloading.
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your download on a different thread (run in the background). That way, the user will continue using the app smoothly. Try the below code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { // in half a second...
    //do your download here
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can I use GCD for doing that?

Comment: What do you mean by cgd?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to transition to `AFHTTPSessionManager`, which uses `NSURLSession`. The old `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` was `NSURLConnection`-based, but `NSURLConnection` is now deprecated. And, in fact, AFNetworking 3.0 has retired `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` entirely.

So, the `AFHTTPSessionManager` download method might look like:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < urlArray.count; i++) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlArray[i]]];
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress *downloadProgress) {
        [self.delegate downloadProgression:downloadProgress.fractionCompleted * 100.0];
    } destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self.documentDirectory getDownloadContentPath:contentPaths[i]]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@" error.localizedDescription);
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I use now. The question is  NSURLSessionTask *task = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request this takes long to create task, and if the loop is very big, say 500 times, this gonna be long.